# How to make Vim respect proper wrapping when opened from Mutt?

Tags: email, vim, terminal, mutt

I am using the line below in my .muttrc Editing generally seems to work except that braking at 79 driving me nuts. I cannot get Vim to stop acting that way. I do not want any braking whatsoever but I want wrapping (based on the terminal screen size)

```
set editor='vim + -c "set wrapmargin=0" -c "set textwidth=0" -c "set wrap"  -c "set nocp" -c "setlocal fo+=aw" -c "set nohlsearch"  -c "?^$"'
```

Is there anything else I can do to make Vim respect wrapping?   I followed some other SU post, with no success :(

Is it possible that Vim is trying to respect the included message? if so how can I overcome it?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want Vim to visually wrap at word boundaries, but keep paragraphs as single lines within the actual file.  If so, remove this:

```
setlocal fo+=aw
```

And add this:

```
setlocal linebreak
```

Also, I would like to point out that you don't need a separate `set` command for each option, just put them all together.  For example:

```
set editor='vim + -c "setlocal wrapmargin=0 textwidth=0 wrap nocp linebreak nohlsearch"  -c "?^$"'
```

Note that the `setlocal` command behaves as `set` for options that cannot be set locally.

Answer (score 3):

The correct way to do it, is to add all mutt specific options to a file called `~/.vim/ftplugin/mail.vim` and make sure to include the statement `:filetype plugin indent on` in your .vimrc. Then Vim will use these settings automatically when writing Mails from within mutt and you don't need to edit your .muttrc to specify different options.

I have further enhanced and customized it. See [here](http://www.256bit.org/~chrisbra/cms/vim_as_e-mail_editor.html)